# Анимация одного блока при нажатии на другой блок

Tags: javascript, jquery

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить следующую задачу.

Скрипт - это иконка меню (три полоски), при нажатии на которую происходит анимация, и она становится крестиком. При повторном нажатии она снова преобразуется в три полоски, т.е. возвращается в исходное положение. Блок `div` с классом `icon` шириной 100%.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы при нажатии не только на иконку, но и на сам блок с классом `icon`, происходила анимация иконки.

Сейчас анимация иконки происходит непосредственно при нажатии на саму иконку.

```js
$(function() {
  $('.hmbrgr.four').hmbrgr({
    width: 30,
    height: 22,
    barHeight: 3,
    barRadius: 3,
    barColor: '#2a2a2a'
  });
});

(function($) {

  $.fn.hmbrgr = function(settings) {

    var config = $.extend({
      width: 30,
      height: 22,
      speed: 200,
      barHeight: 3,
      barRadius: 0,
      barColor: '#ffffff',
      animation: 'expand',
      onInit: null,
      onOpen: null,
      onClose: null
    }, settings);

    var posTop = 0,
      posMiddle = (config.height / 2) - (config.barHeight / 2),
      posBottom = config.height - config.barHeight;

    function hmbrgrBuild(el) {
      $(el)
        .css({
          'width': config.width,
          'height': config.height
        })
        .html('<span /><span /><span />')
        .find('span').css({
          'position': 'absolute',
          'width': '100%',
          'height': config.barHeight,
          'border-radius': config.barRadius,
          'background-color': config.barColor,
          'transition-duration': config.speed + 'ms'
        });

      hmbrgrSpanReset(el);
      $.isFunction(config.onInit) && config.onInit.call(this);
    }

    function hmbrgrSpanReset(el) {
      $(el)
        .data('clickable', true)
        .find('span').eq(0).css({
          'top': posTop
        });

      $(el)
        .find('span').eq(1).css({
          'top': posMiddle
        });

      $(el)
        .find('span').eq(2).css({
          'top': posBottom
        });
    }

    function hmbrgrCommand(el) {
      $(el).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if ($(this).data('clickable')) {

          $(this).data('clickable', false);

          $(el).toggleClass('cross');

          if ($(el).hasClass('cross'))
            hmbrgrExpand(el);
          else
            hmbrgrCollapse(el);
        }
      });
    }

    function hmbrgrExpand(el) {
      $(el).find('span').css({
        top: posMiddle
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        $(el).addClass(config.animation).data('clickable', true);
        $.isFunction(config.onOpen) && config.onOpen.call(this);
      }, config.speed);
    }

    function hmbrgrCollapse(el) {
      $(el).removeClass(config.animation);

      setTimeout(function() {
        hmbrgrSpanReset(el);
        $.isFunction(config.onClose) && config.onClose.call(this);
      }, config.speed);
    }

    return this.each(function() {
      hmbrgrBuild(this);
      hmbrgrCommand(this);
    });

  };

}(jQuery));
```

```css
.icon {
  height: 42px;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: none;
  text-align: center;
}
.hmbrgr {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.hmbrgr span {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
}

.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(1) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(2) {
  zoom: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-opacity: 0;
  -moz-opacity: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}
.hmbrgr.expand span:nth-child(3) {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="icon">
  <section class="four">
    <a href="#" class="hmbrgr four"></a>
  </section>
</div>
```